# HTML code for two-paged PDF

Tags: pdf, html

What HTML-code snippet must be included so when you create a PDF in CiviCRM, you would create a two-paged PDF?

One contact, one PDF, two pages, and the desired page break at a position of my own choice.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

`<div style="page-break-before:always;"></div>`

Works for us, using wkhtmltopdf rather than the default.